# Which is correct, "are you going" or "will you go"?

Tags: grammar, future

1. You look so smart. Will you go to the job interview?
2. You look so smart. Are you going to the job interview?

This was on my exam today, so I want to find out which one is correct.

Comment: Both are correct, but "Are you going" connects better with your friend being dressed up.

Comment: Neither is grammatically wrong, but the second is more natural ('Are you dressed smartly _because_ you are going to an interview?')

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/will-vs-going-to

Answer (score 1):

> (1) You look so smart. Will you go to the job interview?

> (2) You look so smart. Are you going to the job interview?

Both (1) and (2) are grammatically valid and natural. Any question asking "which is right?" of these two is in my view a poor question.

That said (2) seems to imply that the interview is in the very immediate future, and thus connects better with "*You look so smart.*" as one might well dress up for an interview. Sentence (1) suggests that the interview is further ahead, probably not the same day, and so there is less connection with "*You look so smart.*", although that might refer tom a new hairstyle or some other aspect that lasts more than a day. Two comments made this same point.